# Websocket, State Management and Null Values on Updates

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket, state

I have a simple component. Which consumes an API. That API is `{items: [{..}]), statuses: {..}}`. Doesn't matter what is inside the `items` and `statuses`. Data are coming as they should. But there is one problem.

The WS, sends updates and on each message I can either have `statuses` or `items`. Meaning when the `items` are populated in one message, the `statuses` is null. The second message the opposite.

```
[Message 1]
{
  type: 'DATA',
  data: {
    items: [{..}],
    statuses: null
  }
}

[Message 2]
{
  type: 'DATA',
  data: {
    items: null,
    statuses: {..}
  }
}
```

My component works great until the second message. Then everything goes wrong. Screen goes blank, cause, the items, are null, instead of their value. Do you have any idea, how to manage my state, to ignore the `null` values for each key.?? Thank you!

Comment: It should be as simple as `if (items === null)`, but you didn't post your code that handles the updates, so I can't tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Sadly it is not that. I need to handle the `null` and skip it as a value. Basically, say read the prevState. I cannot share the code, it is quire compartmented, and not shareable with out a lot of work. I was hoping for some kind of example online. Thanks though.

Comment: "handle the `null` and skip it as a value" doesn't really mean anything in the absence of context for how your code handles incoming messages. I can't really think of a scenario in which a simple null check wouldn't suffice, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.